# How Can I Communicate RS485 Device With PC

Tags: rs232

I'm trying to communicate with a RS485 device with my PC. I connected RS485 device to RS485-RS232 converter. RS485-RS232 converter is connected to the USB-RS232 converter and USB-RS232 converter is connected to my pc.

I can send commands to RS485 device and device receives and procces my commands. But I can't receive any response from RS485 device.

RS485 Device has 2 pins. (A and B)
RS485-RS232 Converter's RS485 side has 4 pins. (T+,T-,R+,R-)
RS485-RS232 Converter's RS232 side has RS232 DB25 socket.
USB-RS232 Converter has DB9 socket.

My RS485-RS232 converter : https://www.aten.com/au/en/products/data-communication/industry-controls/ic485s/

My USB-RS232 converter : https://www.digitus.info/de/produkte/computer-zubehoer-und-komponenten/computer-zubehoer/seriell-und-parallel-adapter/da-70156/?PL=tr

Rs485 device : https://entes.com.tr/epr_serisi_guc_ve_enerji_olcerler_ud.asp?livecatID=8&livecataltID=18&urunID=1

I tried everything but I cant receive any response from device.

How can I connect this device to my PC.

Comment: Using USB-to-RS485 converter is the best option. Double convertion is always problematic...

Answer (score 0):

You don't say too much what you have tried and how you have connected it. First of all as the device has two pins (half duplex rx/tx port) and adapter has 4 pins (transmit port and receive port), you must connect rx pins to tx pins. Then you must enable RS485 type handshaking as the adapter must be in listen mode when it is not transmitting, and enable RTS only during transmission.